# Distribution and expected value of a random infinite series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(\text{lcm} (n,r_n))^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, probability-distributions, least-common-multiple

> Can we find the distribution and/or expected value of $$S=\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{(\text{lcm} (n,r_n))^2}$$
>
> where $r_n$ is a uniformly distributed random integer, $r_n \in [1,n]$ and $\text{lcm}$ is the least common multiple?

Or maybe an estimate is possible?

Some boundaries are easy to see. For example:

$$1<S \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \approx 1.645$$

For two trials with $10000$ runs each and summing up to $n=20000$ I obtained the following distributions:

[image]

It seems as if there are two peaks.

For 20000 trials we obtain the following distribution:

[image]

For 100000 trials:

[image]

Comment: Cool question! I can compute the distribution of $gcd(n, X)$ for a uniform random $X \in [n]$, but it's not clear to me how to understand the distribution of $lcm(n, X) = n X / gcd(n, X).$

Comment: This paper -- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0536.pdf -- might be useful. The authors describe the limiting behavior of the distribution of least common multiple of some number of uniformly chosen integers in [0,n]. I guess you want to take the lcm of $n$ with a random integer... but maybe some of the same techniques can be used to compute it.

Comment: @JRichey, thank you. This might be more useful for my other question, which has a bounty set rn. So if you want to make it into an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find an expression for the expected value of $S$ in terms of zeta function values.

We have
$$
\mathbf{E}(S)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{E} \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(n,r_n)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(n,j)^2}.
$$

We follow the proof of Theorem 7.1 in a paper by O. Bordelles [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Bordelles2/bordelles61.pdf).

The sum over $j$ becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(n,j)^2}&= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\mathrm{gcd}(n,j)^2}{n^2j^2}\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{d|n} d^2 \sum_{\substack{{j=1}\\{(j,n)=d}}}^n \frac1{j^2}=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{d|n} \sum_{\substack{{k\leq \frac nd}\\{(k,\frac nd)=1}}} \frac1{k^2}.
\end{align}
$$
In the second equality we use $\gcd(n,j)=d$. In the third equality, we use $j=dk$.

We use this into the following sum over $n$.

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\leq x} &\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(n,j)^2} =\sum_{n\leq x} \frac1{n^3} \sum_{d|n} \sum_{\substack{{k\leq \frac nd}\\{(k,\frac nd)=1}}} \frac1{k^2}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x} \frac1{d^3} \sum_{h\leq \frac xd} \frac1{h^3} \sum_{\substack{{k\leq h}\\{(k,h)=1}}} \frac1{k^2} \ (\textrm{ by }n=dh)\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x} \frac1{d^3}\sum_{h\leq \frac xd} \frac1{h^3}\sum_{\delta|h} \frac{\sum_{m\leq h/\delta} \mu(\delta)}{\delta^2 m^2} \ (\textrm{ by introducing }\delta|h, \delta|k, \mu(\delta), k=\delta m)\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x}\frac1{d^3}\sum_{\delta\leq \frac xd}\frac{\mu(\delta)}{\delta^5} \sum_{a\leq \frac x{d\delta}} \frac1{a^3}\sum_{m\leq a}\frac1{m^2} \ (\textrm{ by }h=\delta a).
\end{align}
$$

The inner double sum over $a$ and $m$, is a well-known Euler sum. The formula is given in Lemma 2.1 of this paper by Ce Xu, Yuhuan Yan, Zhijuan Shi. For the proof, see the citation [9] of this paper: [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X16000883#br0090).

$$
C:=\sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac1{a^3}\sum_{m\leq a} \frac1{m^2} = 3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{9\zeta(5)}2.
$$

Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{d\leq x}&\frac1{d^3}\sum_{\delta\leq \frac xd}\frac{\mu(\delta)}{\delta^5} \sum_{a\leq \frac x{d\delta}} \frac1{a^3}\sum_{m\leq a}\frac1{m^2} =\sum_{d\leq x}\frac1{d^3}\sum_{\delta\leq \frac xd} \frac{\mu(\delta)}{\delta^5} \left( C + O\left( \frac{d^2\delta^2}{x^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{d\leq x} \frac1{d^3}\left(\frac C{\zeta(5)} + O\left(\frac{d^4}{x^4}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{\log x}{x^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{C\zeta(3)}{\zeta(5)} + O\left( \frac{\log x}{x^2}\right).
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, we obtain
$$
\mathbf{E}(S)=\frac{\zeta(3)\left(3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{9\zeta(5)}2\right)}{\zeta(5)}.
$$

From this Wolfram Alpha input ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta%283%29+%283+zeta%282%29zeta%283%29+-+9zeta%285%29%2F2%29%2Fzeta%285%29)), the value of the above is approximately
$$1.4673050041864341678704408312097934381417563912360385854969000128$$

Comment: I did not expect such a nice value, thank you!